# Adjust width of horizontal slide menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I am using a template that has a built-in horizontal slide menu, but it slides too far (for my taste).  I have inspected it with dev tools, and I can change the width from 650px (400px looks good), but it leaves grey area where the menu used to be.

What am I missing?

http://www.cultcitychi.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following code at the bottom of your stylesheet, I've tested it and it's working perfectly:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    .sidebar-open .site {
        left: -400px !important;
    }

    .slide-menu, .single .slide-menu {
        width: 400px !important;
    }

}
```

Comment: that does work, thank you.  can you point me in the direction of learn how to do that myself?  why wasnt it adjusting an existing CSS tag?

Comment: @pascale You're welcome. You can easily see and tweak all the CSS on your website using the developer tools. Moreover, you could've changed the value of `width` for `.slide-menu, .single .slide-menu` and the value of `left` for `.sidebar-open .site` by locating their code inside your `style.css` stylesheet but a faster equivalent of that is to simply place the modified styles at the bottom of your stylesheet. By the way, can you please mark my answer as the correct one so that users can know this question has been answered.  Thank you.

Comment: mark'd... thanks again

how do I apply the same ease-in-out  of 0.3s as the original?  this code addition overrides the original but it doesnt account for slide, correct?

Comment: You don't need to worry about `transition: .3s all ease-in-out;` since we're only modifying the `width` and the `left` property using the CSS above. The `transition: .3s all ease-in-out;` property will stay the same.